# Design DS with constant operations including most recent element in 0(1)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Design a data structure which supports following operations on a collection of similar elements ( no duplicate element) :

/ adds the element e in collection /

```
void add(Element e);
```

/ deletes the element e from collection assuming e exists in collection /

```
void delete(Element e);
```

/ returns true if element is present in collection; otherwise returns false/

```
boolean contains(Element e);
```

/ returns most recently added element ​that is present ​in​ the​ collection, assuming collection has at least one element /

```
e getMostRecent()
```

All operations have to be O(1). I was thinking of hashmap and array. but how to maintain most recent element?

Comment: Why an array? As for the rest: if all you need is to remember the most recently added element then simply remember the most recently added element.

Comment: if i remove most recently element , most recently added element will change !

Comment: What you want are "Last In, First Out" semantics... Consider using a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). You should be able to work out how to use the stack to implement the desired semantics.

Comment: yo !!! see ma answe b-low...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such structure with amortized time `O(1)` for each query.

So, you can store additional stack with candidates for queries of last type - `getMostRecent()`

When you need to `add` the element - just add it to hasmap(as you say) and push it on top of our additional stack.

When you need to `delete` the element - do nothing with additional stack.

When you need to `find the recent element` - just pop elements from our stack while it doesn't exist in hashmap. When you find existing element - it's most recent.

So, if we made `D` delete queries, `A` add queries and `Q` - 'getMostRecent' queries, the time needed our structure to answer is `O(D + A + Q)`, because if we added element to our stack we can delete it only once.

Comment: getMostRecent is not O(1) in your solution, because you may need to pop deleted elements from the stack, so it would be O(D). If we look at Q getMostRecent calls, the amortized time is O(D/Q) so if D is much larger than Q, we still get more than O(1) for each getMostRecent. You need a hash table which incorporates a linked list, so items are deleted from the list when they are deleted from the hash table.

Comment: what part of "All operations have to be O(1)" don't you understand ?

Answer (score -1):

LinkedHashMap (in java.util) - a hash table (supports insert, delete, exists in constant time) with a linked list which keeps the insertion order (supports getLast using an iterator in constant time).